# Load local XML file values into Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, xml, local, hta

Trying read various values from a local (c:\folder\xmlfile.xml) XML config file and put them into JavaScript variables within an HTA that is also running on the same local machine.

The local XML file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Module name="LocalDB">
        <Property name="Server" value="localhost\application" />
        <Property name="Database" value="applicationdb" />
        <Property name="UID" value="standarduser" />
        <Property name="Password" value="defaultpw" />
   </Module>
</configure>
```

I need to put the various values such as "applicationdb", "standarduser", "defaultpw", into JavaScript variables after opening and reading the XML file.

I've been trying all day, and maybe my google-fu isn't as strong as I thought but can't seem to find any real direction.

I've gotten as far as:

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
while(xmlDOC.readyState !=4) {};
xmlDOC=loadXMLDoc("xmlfile.xml");
```

I'm not entirely sure even that is correct, but I haven't been able to find instruction on how to parse the values once the file is loaded.

Thanks for taking the time to read and for your help.

Comment: Here is interesting article which may help you http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript

Comment: Mqybe this will help: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Loading local files shouldn't be possible IMO. Would be very unsafe. Not even for a local page. A handy support table: http://www.steveborn.com/codenotes/LoadingXML.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your xmlfile.xml is not a valid xml file. The closing Configuration tag is incorrectly spelt and will failed to load. Once you fix that, you should consider using XPATH queries to search your XML.

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
xmlDoc.load('xmlfile.xml'); // TODO: validate true
var xmlElem = xmlDoc.documentElement; // TODO: validate not null
var xmlServer = xmlElem.selectSingleNode('//Property[@name=\'Server\']');
var strServer = xmlServer.getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code works perfectly. The XML file I have listed above wasn't a copy/paste so the real file does contain a valid closing tag. I was using a different method and was able to get it to work however your code is much more clean so I may switch to this.